# react-navigation swipe back on android is not working

Tags: android, react-native

Currently i do have this config in react-navigation:

```js
<Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}
 <Stack.Group
        screenOptions={{
          contentStyle: { marginTop: 120 },
          gestureEnabled: true,
          // presentation: 'modal',
          gestureDirection: 'horizontal',
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen component={CollectiblesInfoScreen} name={Routes.COLLECTIBLE_INFO_SCREEN} />
      </Stack.Group>
</Stack.Navigator>
```

but for some reason when i try to swipe down nothing happens, modals do not close. Currently this is how it looks like the component `CollectiblesInfoScreen`

```js
import { Box, Text } from 'native-base';

export const CollectiblesInfoScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Text>Test</Text>
    </Box>

  );
};
```

Any ideas about what might be the issue?